# Meaning of some operators in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

What means the following piece of code in javascript:

```
  var lO1 = ~~$('html').css('padding-left').replace('px', '');
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Break it down step by step and you should be able to figure out what the whole thing does.